# Melt function with numerical entries in R

Tags: r, reshape2

I have the following problem with the melt function in R (which is part of the reshape2 package).

Say I have the following example:

```
library(reshape2)
# I start with a matrix and create a data frame 
# who's first column is a numbering of the rows.
HH <- matrix(0, nrow = 10, ncol = 20)
df <- data.frame( pp = 1:10, HH)
# Then I melt it using the row number as a pivot (or id).
df <- melt(df ,  id.vars = 'pp', variable.name = 'time')
```

What I get is the right kind of matrix, but the "Time" data contains elements of the kind `x1`, ... , `x2` and I would really like numerical values for later use (say 1,...,2). I suppose there must be some very intelligent way to achieve this, other than writing a code that changes the names of all the entries.

Comment: `df$time <- as.numeric(substr(df$time, 2, 999))`?

Comment: I am quite new at programming, so to be sure I understand what's going on: substr chooses all the characters after the first one and as.numeric sees them as a numeric element? Practically you are cancelling the "x".

Comment: yes, I am basically stripping the first character off of the text and then coercing it to a numeric

Comment: You can get rid of the "x" in the column names during the `data.frame` step by adding `check.names = FALSE`, but you'll still end up with a `factor` column (not a numeric one) when you melt. So, you'll still have to do it in two steps. Is there any problem with your present approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a case where the "tidyverse" can help, specifically by using the `convert` argument in `gather`. I've also changed how you create the `data.frame` by adding a `check.names = FALSE` to the `data.frame(...)` step. Note, however, that you'll end up with syntactically invalid names with that approach, but since your target dataset structure is different, it shouldn't matter.

Example:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(pp = 1:10, HH, check.names = FALSE)
gather(df, key, value, -pp, convert = TRUE)

str(gather(df, key, value, -pp, convert = TRUE))
# 'data.frame': 200 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ pp   : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#  $ key  : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#  $ value: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```